# How can I disable meta format-detection on iOS for dates?

Tags: ios, meta-tags

I realize that there is a meta tag for disabling the auto formatting of a telephone number in iOS but I wondered if its possible in iOS for things like a date or time.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

There is no meta way at the moment. However there are **two** tricks to break the detection.

I advise to split the date/time with a harmless HTML element, like a span:

```
Mon<span></span>day
```

Another trick is adding a zero-width space:

```
Mon&#x200B;day
```

However this is less stable, for example in the preview text of iOS 6-8, there the zero with space is displayed like a regular space.

Answer (score 2):

Add this tag to your header

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="date=no">
```

Comment: Also wanted to add that you should be able to do a comma-separated list within one tag: `<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=yes, date=no" />`

Comment: This is not documented by Apple and actually does not work (at least on iOS 8). Could you provide the source where you got this information from?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible for dates or addresses. Unfortunately, phone numbers are the only type covered in Apple's documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

Answer (score 0):

Or just hide it with css by styling the generated links like

```
your-element-containg-days a {
    color: #000 !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
        }
```

You have to add !important to overrule the generated styling.

Comment: To the person who downvoted this: this is a valid answer. Oftentimes in the email world, one needs to hide auto-generated links instead of completely remove the functionality. It is an effective way to faux-disable these automations.

Comment: The only thing is that this doesn't work with email clients. Otherwise it is a valid solution in html world