# iOS Chrome: Dates automatically preselected to add to calendar

Tags: html

I have date on the page. On iOS device (iPhone 6s) at Chrome, the date is preselected to add to calendar. I want to remove it. Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable meta format-detection on iOS for dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249770/how-can-i-disable-meta-format-detection-on-ios-for-dates)